# Deprecated mysql_query and mysql_connect - code update

Tags: php, mysql

Years ago a friend of mine wrote a piece of code for me to do some simple function of recording a learning progress for my joomla site users. Now that I have updated the Joomla to 3.6 on PHP7, the site is reporting deprecated queries which did not surprise me. I tried to replace the queries with mysqli but I have failed to make the function work. Would someone take a look for me? Thank you so much.

```
<?php
/*      $host = "localhost";
$user = "administrator"; 
$pass = "web-Test";//enter here your sql password
$db_name = "e-learning";
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name, $link)or die("unable to select database");  */
include'const.php';
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user,$pass);
if (!$link) {
echo('Could not connect');
}
else {
mysql_select_db($db, $link) or die("can not select database").mysql_error();    
}   
$ip=getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');  
//$new_array_without_nulls = array_filter($_POST, 'strlen');

if($_POST)
{

// --------comment
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
unset($_POST['uid']);
$cmt = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value != 'true' && $value != 'Progress' && $value != 'false')
        {
            $cmt[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
foreach ($cmt as $key => $value)
$cmt_value = implode(',' , $cmt);
// --------Check 
$check = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value == 'true')
        {
            $check[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
//finding key
$check_key = array();
foreach ($check as $key => $value){
    array_push($check_key,$key);
}
foreach ($check_key as $key => $value)
$check_value = implode(',' , $check_key);   

//$uid = $user->get('id');
$content_name = $_POST['contentname'];
function CheckExistContentName($content_name,$uid){
    $name_exist = mysql_query("select * from Progress where content_name = '$content_name' and User_id = $uid ");
    $arr = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($name_exist))
    {
    $arr = $row;
    }
    return $arr;
}
if(CheckExistContentName($content_name,$uid))
{
    $sql = "update Progress set User_id = '".$uid."', ip = '".$ip."',content_name = '".$content_name."',arr_check = '".$check_value."',arr_cmt = '".$cmt_value."' where content_name = '$content_name' and User_id = $uid";
    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<h2> Your learning progress has been updated </h2>";
}
else 
{
    $sql = "insert into Progress(User_id,ip,content_name,arr_check,arr_cmt) values ('".$uid."','".$ip."','".$content_name."','".$check_value."','".$cmt_value."')";
    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<h2> Your learning progress has been saved </h2>";
}
}
//}
?>
```

Comment: You must be use mysqli query structures.

Comment: You're still using `mysql_` functions in the code. Show the code that you tried to make, and the exact error messages or description of the wrong behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend did it completely wrong in a Joomla sense. He hard coded a MySQL connection (including password) into a file instead of using the Joomla database class.

On top of that he is using unsafe variables directly in his MySQL queries, which means your site is at very high risk of being hacked.

If I was you, I would get a professional to fix this issue properly.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. It seems we should completely get rid of this and start from scratch.